Inject Commands Without ADB
So, I've got a phone here with no screen, and adb isn't enabled (I'm not even sure if developer settings are enabled, to be honest)
I'm looking to extract whatever data I can off of it at the least, and at the most, control the phone remotely from my computer.
I've never done this type of thing without the use of adb, so any help would be greatly appreciated!
